How can I resolve this `Error: You must select all cells in a merged range to merge or unmerge them.` while merging cells through App Script?
I was trying to merge cells in Google Sheets using App Script when multiple rows have the same values in corresponding columns, I aimed to merge the cells based on one column.
Like, I was merging the rest of the corresponding column values by checking the second column's value(index 1). If multiple rows have same values for that column, I want to merge rest of the column values into one for those rows.
Although I'm not able to implement the functionality properly, the merging feature is working partially for the first run. But whenever I add some new rows and try to execute the script again, it's throwing this Error: You must select all cells in a merged range to merge or unmerge them.
Here's the raw data:



Date
Customer Name
Contact Number
Email
Address
Product ID




11/1/2024
Wilma Gibbs
019999999999
myzitune@mailinator.com
Sint magni, Anim, Upsa
Combo-Z


11/1/2024
Dorothy Douglas
012222222222
dorothy@mailinator.com
Incidunt, Minim
Combo-A


11/1/2024
Paloma Wilcox
010000000000
paloma@mailinator.com
Block B/50, Earth
Combo-B


11/1/2024
Paloma Wilcox
010000000000
paloma@mailinator.com
Block B/50, Earth
Combo-B


11/1/2024
Paloma Wilcox
010000000000
paloma@mailinator.com
Block B/50, Earth
Combo-B


11/1/2024
Mari Patrick
016666666666
bymyjego@mailinator.com
A/B Beatae, Consequatu
Combo-A



->> Raw data On the sheet
The result I want:
->> Expected outcome
After running the following function in the Apps Script, I’m getting a corrupted outcome on the first execution. This results in the titled error on every execution afterward!
->> Corrupted outcome
function mergeCustomerOrderRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = "GOOGLE_SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  const mergeColumns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; // I don't want 'Product ID'(index 5) to be merged

  try {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    if (!sheet) throw new Error(`Sheet "${sheetName}" not found.`);

    const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    const data = dataRange.getValues();
    
    let startRowIndex = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][1] === data[i - 1][1]) continue;

      if (startRowIndex < i) {
        mergeColumns.forEach(colIndex => {
          const range = sheet.getRange(startRowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1, i - startRowIndex, 1);
          range.merge();
        });
      }
      startRowIndex = i;
    }

    if (startRowIndex < data.length) {
      mergeColumns.forEach(colIndex => {
        const range = sheet.getRange(startRowIndex+1, colIndex+1, data.length - startRowIndex, 1);
        range.merge();
      });
    }

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Logger.log("Merging completed based on the second column match.");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Merged cells successfully based on second column condition");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


What changes could make it work the way I want?

Can you add your data on your post as Plain Text Table or anything that are easily copied?

Note that merging cells will make it harder, not easier, to use process the data further. It usually makes more sense to use conditional formatting to hide repeated customer names. You may also want to consider using a Group by view.

Thanks @doubleunary for your suggestions.

In your showing script, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?
From:
const range = sheet.getRange(startRowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1, i - startRowIndex, 1);

To:
const range = sheet.getRange(startRowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1, i - startRowIndex, 1);

Note:
As another approach, how about the following sample script?
function mergeCustomerOrderRows() {
  const spreadsheetId = "GOOGLE_SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  const mergeColumns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
  const checkCol = 2; // Column "B". This is from your script.

  try {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let temp = "";
    let tempAr = [];
    const ar = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const v = values[i][checkCol - 1];
      const row = i + 1;
      if (v == temp) {
        tempAr.push(row);
      } else {
        if (tempAr.length > 0) {
          ar.push(tempAr);
        }
        tempAr = [row];
        temp = v;
      }
      if (i == values.length - 1 && tempAr.length > 0) {
        ar.push(tempAr);
      }
    }
    ar.filter(r => r.length > 1).forEach(r => {
      const start = r.shift();
      const end = r.pop();
      mergeColumns.forEach(m => {
        const range = sheet.getRange(`${m}${start}:${m}${end}`);
        if (!range.isPartOfMerge()) {
          range.merge();
        }
      });
    });

    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I thought that this line might not be required to be used.
    Logger.log("Merging completed based on the first column match.");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Merged cells successfully based on first column condition");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

Updated:

I reflected the following reply to the above sample script.

The script you provided is merging the cells in a expected manner for the first execution. It's still throwing the error whenever new data is added to the sheet and try to run again




The script you provided is merging the cells in a expected manner for the first execution. It's still throwing the error whenever new data is added to the sheet and try to run again

@Mikat Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated the sample script. Please confirm it again.

You nailed it @Tanaike! This time it worked successfully. Thanks a lot!
Also can you help me with triggering this function after a couple of minutes whenever I change or add new data/row (through api call or manual edit) to this sheet?

@Mikat About You nailed it @Tanaike! This time it worked successfully. Thanks a lot!, thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

@Mikat About your new question Also can you help me with triggering this function after a couple of minutes whenever I change or add new data/row (through api call or manual edit) to this sheet?, in that case, how about using the time-driven trigger? You can see it at this official document. Ref

I just have got an issue with merging the cells using the script you provided! It's running smoothly untill group of rows with same entities on the second column are at the end, it again runs in an expected manner if I add at least one different row after them, could you help me fixing this?

@Mikat About your new question I just have got an issue with merging the cells using the script you provided! It's running smoothly untill group of rows with same entities on the second column are at the end, it again runs in an expected manner if I add at least one different row after them, could you help me fixing this?, I would like to support you. In this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Okay, thanks @Tanaike
